# Expression is not a method - Bubble sort

Tags: vb.net, bubble-sort

I am writing a classic bubble sort in Visual Basic VB.NET and getting an error BC30454 Expression is not a method.
Code is running into problem when I am starting to sort inserted numbers in first "For". I changed the Sub to Public and double checked that the method was typed correctly but nothing seemed to help.
What did I miss?

```
Sub EE14()
    Dim j As Long, p As Long, n As Long, i As Long, Pole(100) As Long
    Dim s As String
    n = 0
    Do
        i = Val(InputBox("Write a number:"))
        If i <> 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            Pole(n) = i
        End If
    Loop Until i = 0
    For j = 0 To (n - 1)
        For i = 0 To (n - 1)
            If Pole(i) > Pole(i + 1) Then
                p = Pole(i)
                Pole(i) = Pole(i + 1)
                Pole(i + 1)
                Pole(i + 1) = p
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i = 0 To n
        s = s & vbCrLf & Str(Pole(i))
    Next
    MsgBox(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: mistyped - updated

Comment: Seems like it's the `Pole(i + 1)` line. That's an expression that only performs an array access and doesn't do anything else. The VB compiler doesn't permit expressions that have no side effects like changing a variable or calling a function. What did you want that line to do?

Comment: You missed telling us which statement got the error. @ChrisAkridge seems to have worked it out, but we shouldn't have to check every line when you already know which one we should be looking at.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks  Chris Akridge,

My bad, by removing the Pole(i + 1), there is no issue.
Code is working correctly now.

```
Sub EE14()
    Dim j As Long, p As Long, n As Long, i As Long, Pole(100) As Long
    Dim s As String
    n = 0
    Do                 
        i = Val(InputBox("Add Number:"))
        If i <> 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            Pole(n) = i
        End If
    Loop Until i = 0
    For j = 0 To (n - 1) 
        For i = 0 To (n - 1)
            If Pole(i) > Pole(i + 1) Then
                p = Pole(i)
                Pole(i) = Pole(i + 1)
                Pole(i + 1) = p
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i = 0 To n
        s = s & vbCrLf & Str(Pole(i))
    Next
    MsgBox(s)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Some changes, one of which is to remove the number of allowed inputs.  Moved the sort to its own method.

```
Sub EE14()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim Pole As New List(Of Long)
    Dim inp As Long
    Dim s As String
    Do
        s = InputBox("Add Number:")
        If Long.TryParse(s, inp) AndAlso inp > 0L Then
            Pole.Add(inp)
        End If
    Loop Until inp = 0L

    SortListOfLongs(Pole)

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To Pole.Count - 1
        sb.AppendLine(Pole(i).ToString)
    Next
    MsgBox(sb.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub SortListOfLongs(LoL As List(Of Long))
    For j As Integer = 0 To LoL.Count - 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To LoL.Count - 2
            If LoL(i) > LoL(i + 1) Then
                Dim p As Long = LoL(i)
                LoL(i) = LoL(i + 1)
                LoL(i + 1) = p
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```